# Convert java objects to angularjs objects

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs

I am trying to pass list of java objects to `angularjs variable` so I can use their properties in html like `{{object.name}}`. I run angularjs function from script like

```
    angular.element("get angularjs controller element").scope().myfillingFunction(javaObjectsList)

And in angularjs i have method 

    $scope.myfillingFunction = function(list){
        console.log("input: "+list)
        $scope.productList=list;
    }
```

**In console i can see only**

> "Input:"

Comment: Why not just `$scope.myfillingFunction(javaObjectsList)` ?

Comment: How are you passing this java objects, Rest API? Are you sure you have correct response from the server?

Comment: Well i'm passing it to request parameter and i'm sure i have correct response because in my freemarker template i display
'javaObjectsList[0].name' and it's works.

In my Java Controller i have 

request.setParameter("param", javaObjectsList)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the Java object to JSON by encoding it using the Gson library and decoding it back in Angular.

### Java to JSON String

```
List<MyObject> objList = new List<MyObject>();
String objJSON = new Gson().toJson(objList);
```

### JSON to JS Object

```
<script>
  var jsObject = angular.fromJson(<%= objJSON %>);
</script>
```